# mvc3 - ajax form submit and server side validation

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am sure this has been asked already, but I have been trying all the solutions given, but none of the given solution is solving my problem. Probably, I am not implementing it right.

I am using MVC3, razor, jQuery.

I have a new user registration form. Once registration is successful, I want to display the successful message (different on type of registration) in a dialog box.

If there is any error with ModelState, means ModelState.IsValid == false, I want to display errors in ValidationSummary.

View

```
function OnBegin () { alert('begin'); return $('form').validate().form(); }
function OnSuccess () { alert('success'); DisplaySucess()}
function OnFailure () { alert('failure'); }
function DisplaySuccess() {
    var typeOfRegistration = $('input:radio[name=RegistrationType]:checked').val();
    var msg;
    if (typeOfRegistration == 0) {
        msg = "You are successfully enrolled for Algebra classes.";
    }
    if (typeOfRegistration == 1) {
        msg = "You are registered with your email address. Someone would contact you with an email.";
    }
    if (typeOfRegistration == 2) {
        msg = "Thank you for filling up this form. One welcome packet would be delivered with in next 15 days";
    }

    msg = msg.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
    $('#dialog').html(msg);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

```
@model Models.RegistrationModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewRegistration", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { OnBegin="OnBegin", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }))
{ 
  @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div>
    Register<br />
    @Html.RadioButton("RegistrationType ", "0", true) New Algebra class<br />
    @Html.RadioButton("RegistrationType ", "1") New user registration by email<br />
    @Html.RadioButton("RegistrationType ", "2") New user registration by mailing address<br/>
   ..some more types
</div>
<div>
    …here I display/hide controls based on Registration type selected.
        <div>
    @Html.LabelFor("UserName")
    @Html.TextBox("UserName")</div>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult NewRegistration(RegistrationModel model)
{

         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
             if (!ModelState.IsValid) { 
        //Ques: How do I display this in ValidationSummary. 
        return Json(new object[] { false, "Contains Email Address", ModelState.GetAllErrors() }); 
        }
             else { 
        if (UserNameIsTaken){ 
            //Ques: This does not show in ValidationSummary
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "This username is already taken. Please pick a different username.");
        }
       }
    }
         else if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(model); }

}
```

Model

```
public class RegistrationModel: IValidatableObject
{
[Required] //this gets displayed in ValidationSummary as Client-side validation
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    .. and all fields here
}
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && UserName.Contains(EmailAddress)) {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Username cannot contain email address", new[] { "UserName" });
        }
    }
```

Web.config has

> UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled="true" and ClientValidationEnabled="true"

.js files included are

> script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
>
> script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
>
> script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
>
> script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript">

What am I missing here? Any alternative?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Think that posting a form vía ajax you only get client side errors.

Server side errors, need to be returned via Json and then "inserted" in the markup vía jQuery or plain javascript.

[Here you can see and download a fully working example.](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-08-09/asp_net-mvc_3-json-result-jquery-ajax-form-validation)

Comment: After lots of trials and reading I eneded up doing like you suggested. I return Json with false as first parameter of object when there is any server side error. In OnSucess, I grab error checking data[0] == false (means error) and insert it in the ValidationSummary markup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following references in the master file (layout.cshtml):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
```

In web.config, set 'false' to 'true':

```xml
<appSettings>
<!--<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> (enable this when client-side validation is needed) -->
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

In the model:

```c#
public class ValidUserNameAttribue : ValidationAttribute
{
  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
    return (value != null && value.ToString() == "Bob");
  }
}

public class Customer
{
  [ValidUserNameAttribue(ErrorMessage = "please type user name as Bob")] /* for server side validation*/
  public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller:

```c#
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View(new ValidationModel());
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Form(ValidationModel validationModel)
  {
    return PartialView(!ModelState.IsValid ? "Partial/_Form" : "Partial/_Success", validationModel);
  }
}
```

Index View:

```html
@model MVC3_Ajax_Form_jQuery_Validation.Models.ValidationModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ajax form submit and server side validation";
}


<div id="FormContainer">
    @Html.Partial("Partial/_Form")
</div>
```

Form View:

```html
@model MVC3_Ajax_Form_jQuery_Validation.Models.ValidationModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Form", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "FormContainer" , OnSuccess = "$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');" }))
{

    <p>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) // (Error Message)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName):
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Success View:

```html
@model MVC3_Ajax_Form_jQuery_Validation.Models.ValidationModel

User name '@Model.UserName' is valid :)
```

Check out this link for server-side validation in an AJAX form: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460893/Unobtrusive-AJAX-Form-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC